# why tex4ht generate funny looking extra characters when using \usepackage{cprotect} package

Tags: tex4ht

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\cprotect\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
 This is a test 
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

compiled with  `htlatex foo.tex`  generates this html

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="foo.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2015-03-10 14:04:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css"> 
</head><body 
>
   <div class="fbox"><div class="minipage">This is a test</div> &#x02C6;&#x02C6;E&#x02C6;&#x02C6;L</div>

</body></html>
```

file list

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  tex4ht.sty    
cprotect.sty    2011/01/27 v1.0e (Bruno Le Floch)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
 ***********
```

texlive 2014 on Linux. I will also post this to tex4ht mailing list. This looks like a bug. Just posting here for reference or if anyone has an easy workaround. (there is no tag for the cprotect package)

)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `cprotext` documentation:

> Will break if ^ does not have its usual catcode at the beginning and
>   at the end of the \cprotected command. Also, will break if ^^E or ^^L
>   change catcodes. This choice of symbols can be changed by setting the
>   options gobbling-escape = hletter i, and gobbling-letter = hletter i.
>   The defaults are gobbling-escape = E and gobbling-letter = L.

it is well known issue that `^` character has changed catcode with `tex4ht`, so we have to set it temporarily to the normal value. we may create environment, which will have correct catcodes inside, so you can place problematic code here

```
\newenvironment{normalcatcodes}{\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}{}
```

and full example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\newenvironment{normalcatcodes}{\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{normalcatcodes}
\cprotect\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
 This is a test 
\end{minipage}
}
\end{normalcatcodes}
\end{document}
```

the result is correct now:

[image]